# ProgressView not showing progress

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following code inside a collection cell:

```
let progressView: UIProgressView = {
    let progressView = UIProgressView(frame: .zero)
    progressView.progressViewStyle = .bar
    progressView.trackTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.93, green: 0.93, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1.00)
    progressView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.20, green: 0.66, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1.00)
    progressView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    progressView.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return progressView
}()


 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        progressView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
        progressView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
        progressView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: author.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
        progressView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: contentView.frame.width),
        progressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5)
    ])


func handleProgress(progress: Float) {
    progressView.isHidden = false
    progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: false)
}
```

When I call `handleProgress` on the cell, the progress 30% doesn't show on the progress view. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

The value you set should range between 0.0 an 1.0. If you're setting it to 30, that won't work.

Second, you can't set the progress view to different values in a loop. It won't change until the loop completes and your code returns. At that point it will display the final value.

This code should cause your progress view to move from 0 to 1:

```
var progress: CGFloat = 0 

func increaseProgress() {
       progressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
       progress += 0.05
       if progress < 1 {
           DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
              increaseProgress()
       }
}

progress = 0
increaseProgress()
```